# How to remove "starred" tab in gnome's nautilus?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, nautilus, gnome-shell

I have a lot of network drives and a few bookmarks and I don't like having my file manager maximized, so I prefer an interface that's as clean as possible.

[image]

This `Starred` tab however blocks this for me. I've never used it before. Under `gnome 3.28` it wouldn't even work (nothing would show up even when I "Star" it), haven't tried it now with `3.30` but I simply don't need or want this feature at all.

How would I go on about removing this entry from the menu?
And while we're at it: Can I remove the "Recent" one too?

I've went through every settings of `nautilus` itself and also went through its `dconf-editor` folder, couldn't find anything that might help me though.

I just found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235739) - That explains why it doesn't work for me, as I have indexing disabled, but doesn't suggest any solution or way to get rid of it entirely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the auto-detection of whether to show the 'Starred' panel based on whether you have any starred items was decided against. I don't know why it is shown even without Tracker being available, though.

Note that the sidebar is actually a single unit provided by Gtk, *not* an editable collection of random items – but still sufficiently customizable for this purpose.

**Option 1:** Override the built-in UI description.

1. Create a location for the overrides:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.config/nautilus/ui
   ```
2. Extract the resource description of the main window:

   ```
   gresource extract /bin/nautilus \
             /org/gnome/nautilus/ui/nautilus-window.ui \
             > ~/.config/nautilus/ui/nautilus-window.ui
   ```
3. Edit the properties of the GtkPlacesSidebar object:

   ```
   <object class="GtkPlacesSidebar" id="places_sidebar">
     ...
     <property name="show-recent">False</property>
     <property name="show-starred-location">False</property>
     ...
   </object>
   ```
4. Set the environment variable to make GLib use this override:

   ```
   export G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS="/org/gnome/nautilus/ui=$HOME/.config/nautilus/ui"
   ```

   Due to Nautilus being started via D-Bus, you will likely need to set this via `~/.pam_environment`…

   ```
   G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS DEFAULT="/org/gnome/nautilus/ui=/home/confetti/.config/nautilus/ui"
   ```

   …or via `~/.config/systemd/user/dbus.service.d/environment.conf`:

   ```
   [Service]
   Environment="G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS=/org/gnome/nautilus/ui=/home/confetti/.config/nautilus/ui"
   ```

**Option 2:** Recompile Nautilus with this patch applied:

```
diff --git a/src/nautilus-window.c b/src/nautilus-window.c
index 0d1234f15..7a6d567f6 100644
--- a/src/nautilus-window.c
+++ b/src/nautilus-window.c
@@ -1347,6 +1347,12 @@ nautilus_window_set_up_sidebar (NautilusWindow *window)
                                         | GTK_PLACES_OPEN_NEW_TAB
                                         | GTK_PLACES_OPEN_NEW_WINDOW));

+    gtk_places_sidebar_set_show_recent (GTK_PLACES_SIDEBAR (window->places_sidebar),
+                                        FALSE);
+
+    gtk_places_sidebar_set_show_starred_location (GTK_PLACES_SIDEBAR (window->places_sidebar),
+                                                  FALSE);
+
     g_signal_connect_swapped (window->places_sidebar, "open-location",
                               G_CALLBACK (open_location_cb), window);
     g_signal_connect (window->places_sidebar, "show-error-message",
```

Comment: I've tried option 1 and did step 4 with the `[Service]` one (please note that I had no `~/.config/systemd` directory, I've created it) but it didn't do anything. Do I have to restart my system?

Comment: Yes, in order for dbus-daemon to pick up the new environment variables.

Comment: Just restarted my system, there are however no changes. Should I try the `~/.pam_environment` method or troubleshoot somewhere else?

Comment: Perhaps the method is no longer effective with GNOME 3.30. (I use a code patch.)

Comment: My apologies, I've just now noticed that you've hardcoded `confetti` as username in it, that's probably why it doesn't work lol. I'll change that and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now exactly as intended. It might sound stupid, but that extra space really makes a difference for me.

Comment: When I tried step 2 in option 1 on with GNOME 3.36.3 and Ubuntu 20.04.1 I got 
```Don't know how to handle /bin/nautilus
gresource is built without elf support```. If any one knows how to address this, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

To the second part of your question. To remove the "Recent" tab, run this command under your user:

```bsh
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.privacy remember-recent-files false
```

Alas, I can't find the similar command for the "Starred" tab.